# differential equation with 3 equalities

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

please if you can help me to solve this differential equation : 
$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{z}$

I tried solving it taking two equalities at a time

Answer (score 1):

$$\int{dx\over x}=\int{dy\over y}=\int{dz\over z}$$ $$\log x=\log y+C=\log z+D$$ for some constants $C$ and $D$.

Comment: How to find a relation between x y and z ... i mean f(x,y,z)=0 ?

Comment: What makes you think the solution is given by such an $f$? Exponentiating the equation with the logarithms gives $z=Ay=Bx$ for some constants $A$, $B$.